# Google information about user not showing in console! (Google login)

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, google-oauth, google-signin, console.log

having this issue that
** "I'm not getting the Profile-obj of user if log in with a google id!" **
but it shows my ClientID and credentials:

and there is this warning about indicate** same-Site attribute** is this warning causing this issue, if so please help me how to add Same-Site Attribute and where "I'm confused"

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSYwQ.png)
I tried adding Same-Site attribute in '' but no luck as for the not "getting info" I don't know what to do for that!
sorry for the bad English! please help anyone! I'm stuck here

Answer (score 0):

The credential is JWT encoded and it needs to be decoded first.

for more info Visit https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#CredentialResponse

jwt_decode package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode